# Error when i trying to start web app with maven deploy, Java

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets

```
 Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: For input string: "port" -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project 18_servlets_jsp: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: For input string: "port"
```

This exception i got when i try to deploy my app with servlets.

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nixsolutions.ppp</groupId>
    <artifactId>18_servlets_jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.52</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.Boot</mainClass>
                            <name>18_servlets_jsp</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nixsolutions.ppp</groupId>
            <artifactId>interfaces</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://domain:port/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://domain:port/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.nixdev.co/api/v4/groups/446/-/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>corp1</id>
            <name>Corporate Repository</name>
            <url>scp://repo/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Servlet class

```
package com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.servlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


@WebServlet(
        name = "Servlet",
        urlPatterns = {"/hello"}
)
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        out.write("hello heroku".getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Boot class

```
package com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp;

//import com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.entity.Person;
//import com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.entity.Role;
//import com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.jdbcConnect.ConnectionManager;
//import com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.factoryDAO.PersonDAOFactory;
//import com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.factoryDAO.RoleDAOFactory;
//import com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.genericDAO.GenericDAO;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;
//import java.util.Optional;
//import java.util.Scanner;

public class Boot {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Boot.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, LifecycleException {
        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/java/com/nix/dmitrij_dudka/servlets_jsp/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        //The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
        //Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }

        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

        StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        // Declare an alternative location for your "WEB-INF/classes" dir
        // Servlet 3.0 annotation will work
        File additionWebInfClasses = new File("target/classes");
        WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
        resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes",
                additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
        ctx.setResources(resources);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.nix.dmitrij_dudka.servlets_jsp.servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Output in terminal after command `mvn -e deploy`:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< com.nixsolutions.ppp:18_servlets_jsp >----------------
[INFO] Building 18_servlets_jsp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appassembler-maven-plugin:2.0.0:assemble (default) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[WARNING] The usage of program name (18_servlets_jsp) is deprecated. Please use program.id instead.
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/com/nixsolutions/ppp/interfaces/0.5/interfaces-0.5.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/com/nixsolutions/ppp/interfaces/0.5/interfaces-0.5.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.52/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.52/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/9.0.52/tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/9.0.52/tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/9.0.52/tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/9.0.52/tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.52/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.52/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/ecj/3.18.0/ecj-3.18.0.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/eclipse/jdt/ecj/3.18.0/ecj-3.18.0.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jasper/9.0.52/tomcat-jasper-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jasper/9.0.52/tomcat-jasper-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/9.0.52/tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/9.0.52/tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/9.0.52/tomcat-juli-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/9.0.52/tomcat-juli-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-el-api/9.0.52/tomcat-el-api-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-el-api/9.0.52/tomcat-el-api-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/9.0.52/tomcat-api-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/9.0.52/tomcat-api-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util-scan/9.0.52/tomcat-util-scan-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util-scan/9.0.52/tomcat-util-scan-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/9.0.52/tomcat-util-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/9.0.52/tomcat-util-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jasper-el/9.0.52/tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jasper-el/9.0.52/tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jsp-api/9.0.52/tomcat-jsp-api-9.0.52.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jsp-api/9.0.52/tomcat-jsp-api-9.0.52.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.13.3/log4j-core-2.13.3.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.13.3/log4j-core-2.13.3.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/18_servlets_jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/repo/com/nixsolutions/ppp/18_servlets_jsp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/18_servlets_jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[INFO] Installing /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/target/18_servlets_jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/com/nixsolutions/ppp/18_servlets_jsp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/18_servlets_jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/dmitrijdudka/dmitrij.dudka/18_servlets_jsp/pom.xml to /home/dmitrijdudka/.m2/repository/com/nixsolutions/ppp/18_servlets_jsp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/18_servlets_jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ 18_servlets_jsp ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.593 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-03T15:58:18+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project 18_servlets_jsp: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: For input string: "port" -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project 18_servlets_jsp: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: For input string: "port"
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
                                                                         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke ()ethod.java:566
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: For input string: "port"
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
                                                           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "port"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString (NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:652)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:770)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.PathUtils.port (PathUtils.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.repository.Repository.setUrl (Repository.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.repository.Repository.<init> (Repository.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init> (WagonTransporter.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance (WagonTransporterFactory.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter (DefaultTransporterProvider.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init> (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:129)
    atBasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:155)RepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance (
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector (DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

i have jar file to this project, but i can't create a war file to start this app in tomcat, how i can do it and what i should do with this error?
T.y.`enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://domain:port/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://domain:port/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

DistributionManagement controls the binary artifact manager where java artifacts are deployed (in the sense of "uploaded", not in the sense of "deployed into an application container" which it seems you are referring to).

Since http://domain:port does not exist, the maven-deploy-plugin deploy goal fails (in particular, because it cannot parse `port` as a number).